# How can I create a reusable HTML string object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

How can I create a reusable string for my HTML web page?

I would like the following line of HTML to be reusable as a small string "object" throughout my web pages:

```
[<span class="sgreentxt">root</span>@<span class="sbluetxt">localhost</span> <span class="sorangetxt">~ </span>]
```

Which would be "[root@localhost ~ ]" as interpreted by the webrowser and displayed on the screen.

This object would be equivalent to "cli = [root@localhost ~ ]" so instead of typing that big long string of code I would instead only have to type something like "cli" and the html would recognize it as a javascript string printline or something and output the other code instead which would be interpreted as html and displayed appropriatly. How can I accomplish this and be able to do it multiple times through the same web page. Note: document.getElementById() only works once per web page.

Answer (score 0):

There are great client side template libraries out there.  Personally I like http://handlebarsjs.com/.  This to me looks like more of a server side thing.  You probably want your server to do this for you.  If you really wanted to do it client side and don't care that their *might* be SEO implications and FOUSC artifacts and a proper template library is too much then you might do something like this.

```js
var template = "[<span class=\"sgreentxt\">root</span>@<span class=\"sbluetxt\">localhost</span> <span class=\"sorangetxt\">~ </span>]";
var targets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[data-replace='cli']"));
targets.forEach(function(target) { target.outerHTML = template; });
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span data-replace="cli"></span></li>
  <li><span data-replace="cli"></span></li>
  <li><span data-replace="cli"></span></li>
  <li><span data-replace="cli"></span></li>
</ul>
```